# How to reduce the code space for a hexadecimal ASCII chars conversion using a _small_ code space?

Tags: embedded, pic, bootloader

How to reduce the code space for a hexadecimal ASCII chars conversion using a **small code space?**

In an embedded application, I have extraordinary limited space (note 1).  I need to convert bytes, from serial I/O,  with the ASCII values '0' to '9' and 'A' to 'F' to the usual hexadecimal values 0 to 15.  Also, all the other 240 combinations, including 'a' to 'f', need to be detected (as an error).

Library functions such as `scanf(), atoi(), strtol()` are *far* too large to use.

Speed is not an issue.  Code size is the the limiting factor.

My present method re-maps the 256 byte codes into 256 codes such that '0' to '9' and 'A' to 'Z' have the values 0 - 35.  **Any ideas on how to reduce or different approaches are appreciated.**

```
unsigned char ch = GetData(); // Fetch 1 byte of incoming data;
if (!(--ch & 64)) {           // decrement, then if in the '0' to '9' area ...
  ch = (ch + 7) & (~64);      // move 0-9 next to A-Z codes
}
ch -= 54;                     // -= 'A' - 10 - 1
if (ch > 15) { 
  ; // handle error
}
```

---

Note 1:  256 instructions exist for code and constant data (1 byte data costs 1 instruction) in a PIC protected memory for a bootloader.  This code costs ~10 instructions.  Current ap needs a re-write & with only 1 spare instruction, **reducing even 1 instruction** is valuable.  I'm going through it piece by piece.  Also have looked at overall reconstruction.

Notes: PIC16.  I prefer to code in 'C', but must do what ever it takes.  Assembly code follows.  A quick answer is not required.

```
if (!(--ch & 64)) { 
  002D:DECF   44,F   002E:BTFSC  44.6    002F:GOTO   034     
  ch = (ch + 7) & (~64); 
  0030:MOVLW  07     0031:ADDWF  44,W    0032:ANDLW  BF    0033:MOVWF  44
}// endif 
ch -= 54; 
  0034:MOVLW  36     0035:SUBWF  44,F
```

[edit **best solution**]
Optimizing existing solution as suggested by @GJ. In C, performing the `ch += 7; ch &= (~64);` instead of `ch = (ch + 7) & (~64);` saved 1 instruction. Going to assembly saved another by not having to reload `ch` within the `if()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PIC16 family is RISC MCPU, so you can try to optimize your asm code.
This is your c compilers asm code...

```
    decf    ch, f
    btfsc   ch, 6
    goto    Skip
    movlw   07
    addwf   ch, w
    andlw   0xBF
    movwf   ch
Skip    
    movlw   0x36
    subwf   ch, f
```

This is my optimization of upper code...

```
   decf     ch, w         //WREG = (--ch)
   btfsc    WREG, 6       //if (!(WREG & 64)) {
   goto     Skip  
   addlw    7             //WREG += 7
   andlw    0xBF          //WREG &= (~64)
Skip
   addlw    0x100 - 0x36  //WREG -= 54;
   movwf    ch            //ch = WREG
//
   addlw    0x100 - 0x10  //if (WREG > 15) { 
   btfsc    STATUS, 0     //Check carry
   goto     HandleError
```

...so only 7 opcodes (2 less) without range error check and 10 opcodes with range error check!

**EDIT:
Try also this PIC16 c compiler optimized function, not sure if works...**

```
WREG = (--ch);                   
if (!(WREG & 64)) {              // decrement, then if in the '0' to '9' area ...
  WREG = (WREG + 7) & (~64);     // move 0-9 next to A-Z codes
}
ch = WREG - 54;                  // -= 'A' - 10 - 1 
if (WREG > 15) {    
  ; // handle error 
}
```

**EDIT II: added version which is compatible with older PIC16 MCPUs not made in XLP technology, but code size is one opcode longer.**

```
    decf    ch, f         ;//ch = (--ch)
    movf    ch, w         ;//WREG = ch
    btfsc   ch, 6         ;//if (!(ch & 64)) {
    goto    Skip  
    addlw   7             ;//WREG += 7
    andlw   0xBF          ;//WREG &= (~64)
Skip
    addlw   0x100 - 0x36  ;//WREG -= 54;
    movwf   ch            ;//ch = WREG
//    
    addlw   0x100 - 0x10  ;//if (WREG > 15) { 
    btfsc   STATUS, 0     ;//Check carry
    goto    HandleError
```

**EDIT III: explanation**

The 'D Kruegers'  solution is also very good, but need some modification...

This code..

```
  if (((ch += 0xC6) & 0x80) || !((ch += 0xF9) & 0x80)) {
    ch += 0x0A;
  }
```

...we can translate to...

```
  if (((ch -= ('0' + 10)) < 0) || ((ch -= ('A' - '0' - 10)) >= 0)) {
    ch += 10; 
  }
```

After that we can optimize in asembler...

```
        call    GetData 
//if GetData return result in WREG then you do not need to store in  ch and read it again!
//      movwf   ch
//      movf    ch, w

        addlw   0x100 - '0' - 10     //if (((WREG -= ('0' + 10)) < 0) || ((WREG -= ('A' - '0' - 10)) >= 0)) {
        btfss   STATUS, 0   
        goto    DoAddx
        addlw   0x100 - ('A' - '0' - 10)
        btfsc   STATUS, 0       
    DoAddx
        addlw   10                   //WREG += 10; }
        movwf   ch                   //ch = WREG;       

        addlw   0x100 - 0x10         //if (WREG > 15) { 
        btfsc   STATUS, 0            //Check carry
        goto    HandleError
```

Comment: Is `btfsc WREG, 6` valid on a PIC16?

Comment: @D Krueger: WREG is accessible only on newer PIC16 and PIC12 MCPUs marked as XLP technology. WREG is a copy of ALU working register at address 0x09.

Comment: @Krueger: added also a version which is compatible with older PIC16 MCPUS.

Comment: Thanks.  In `C`, performing the `ch += 7; ch &= (~64);` instead of `ch = (ch + 7) & (~64);` saved 1 instruction.  Going to assembly save another.

Comment: @chux: check also my EDIT III explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

With good compiler optimization, this may take less code space:

```
unsigned char ch = GetData(); // Fetch 1 byte of incoming data;

if (((ch += 0xC6) & 0x80) || !((ch += 0xF9) & 0x80)) {
  ch += 0x0A;
}

if (ch > 15) { 
  ; // handle error
}
```

Comment: This code isn't OK! What should be the result if input is character @ (0x40)?

Comment: @GJ.If on input `ch == 0x40` then its final value will be `0xff`, which will be caught by the `(ch > 15)` test.

Comment: Thank-you.  My best usage of your answer and variations was still +0 instruction over the original.  (This has 3 branches versus original 2.)  It took a while to understand your nifty approach, but it open up some thought.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps using ctype.h's [`isxdigit()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isxdigit/):

```
if( isxdigit( ch ) )
{
    ch -= (ch >= 'A') ? ('A' - 10) : '0' ;
}
else
{
    // handle error
}
```

Whether that is smaller or not will depend largely on the implementation of `isxdigit` and perhaps your compiler and processor architecture, but worth a try and far more readable. `isxdigit()` is normally a macro so there is no function call overhead.

An alternative is to perform the transformation unconditionally then check the range of the result:

```
ch -= (ch >= 'A') ? ('A' - 10) : 
                    (ch >= '0') ? '0' : 0 ;
if( ch > 0xf )
{
    // handle error
}
```

I suspect this latter will be smaller, but modification of `ch` on error may be unhelpful in some cases, such as error reporting the original value.

Comment: Should that be ('A' - 10) rather than ('A' + 10) since you're subtracting that quantity from ch?

Comment: Thanks - Since `isxdigit()` returns true on `a` to `f`', `ch` takes on the values 42 to 47.  I suppose an `if()` could be added.   Assuming `isxdigit()` isn't some big lookup table, it likely uses 3 `if()`s.

Comment: @chux:  I am not sure what you mean, the result in `ch` will be 0 to 15 as required.  The transformation is performed if the digit is hexadecimal.  Since `isxdigit()` is likely to be a macro you can find its complete definition in ctype.h.

Comment: @chux:  I have added an alternative that does not use `isxdigit()` but which modifies `ch` even if it is not a hex digit.

Comment: `isxdigit()` returns true on 0-9, A-F and a-f.  The 1st solution converts `ch` from 'A' into 10, good, but converts 'a' into 42 and is not detected passed to the // handle error.  The second solution converts ':' to '?' into 10 to 15 and they are not detected in the  // handle error.

Comment: My `isxdigit()` is indeed a macro: `#define isxdigit(x) isamong(x,"0123456789ABCDEFabcdef")`.  Certainly longer than 10 instructions.  BTW, later, I'll be in the wilderness for a few days.

Comment: @Clifford `if ( ch < 0x0 ..` can't never be true for an unsigned char

Comment: @chux:  Your question clearly states  '0' to '9' and 'A' to 'F'.  I simply followed your spec.

Comment: @jeb:  true - even better.

Comment: @chux:  I am being thick I see what you mean about a to f.  It needs an `islower()` test but the solution is increasingly unsatisfactory perhaps.  One solution is to convert lower case to upper case before the transformation and accept lower case hex digits `ch &= 0x20`.