# Conversion from byte (binary) to ASCII in C

Tags: c, byte, pic

I'm working with a PIC microprocessor, and I need to send values from an AD-Converter to a terminal (in this case HyperTerminal). Now, the terminal only understands ASCII. The value the AD-Converter gives a single byte (so ranging from 0 to 255). How can convert this binary number to ASCII?

To be entirely clear, the byte is binary. So `0100 0000` should result in `64`. Ofcourse this would mean needing to send 2 ASCII numbers to the pc.

**Edit:** Apparently I'm not entirely clear here. I need to have the ASCII-code of the binary number in binary as well so I can send it through a USB-template provided by the chip-manufacturer.

**Edit 2:** After some more delving into other topics, [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/65489/33807) answer led me to trying out `itoa()` and `utoa()`. Now, `itoa()` works, but unfortunately is for unsigned charachters. `utoa()` would be for unsigned chars, but that doesn't work. Here's an example of what should be able to happen:

```
char USB_In_Buffer[64];
char myValue = 0x55;

itoa(myValue, USB_In_Buffer);
putUSBUSART(USB_In_Buffer, 3);
```

So every ASCII character should be sent to `USB_In_Buffer`. Then the total of characters written to this buffer should be used as second parameter in `putUSBUSART()`. I only need to convert numbers to ASCII as well, so not the whole characterset needs to be implemented.

**Edit 3:** Because some automated functions do not appear to be supported, I thought it wouldn't be that hard to make my own function.

```
if(ADCONvalue/100 != 0){
    res++;
    USB_In_Buffer[0] = (ADCONvalue / 100) + 0x30;
}
if(ADCONvalue/10 != 0){
    res++;
    if(res == 1){
        USB_In_Buffer[0] = (ADCONvalue / 10) + 0x30;
    }else{
        USB_In_Buffer[1] = (ADCONvalue / 10) + 0x30;
    }   

}
res++;
if(res == 1){
    USB_In_Buffer[0] = ADCONvalue % 10 + 0x30;
}else if(res == 2){
    USB_In_Buffer[1] = ADCONvalue % 10 + 0x30;
}else{
    USB_In_Buffer[2] = ADCONvalue % 10 + 0x30;
}
putUSBUSART(USB_In_Buffer, res);
```

But there seems to be an error somewhere. Small numbers do work (0-99), but for some reason when there should be `121`, it displays `1<1`. For larger numbers, all the chars are non-numeric.

**Edit 4:** After rechecking my code I found the error. For one, `ADCONvalue` was a `char`, not an `unsigned char`. Also I forgot to do `%10` for the tenths. Current working code:

```
if(ADCONvalue/100 != 0){
    res++;
    USB_In_Buffer[0] = (ADCONvalue / 100) + 0x30;
}
if(ADCONvalue/10 != 0){
    res++;
    if(res == 1){
        USB_In_Buffer[0] = (ADCONvalue / 10)%10 + 0x30;
    }else{
        USB_In_Buffer[1] = (ADCONvalue / 10)%10 + 0x30;
    }   

}
res++;
if(res == 1){
    USB_In_Buffer[0] = ADCONvalue % 10 + 0x30;
}else if(res == 2){
    USB_In_Buffer[1] = ADCONvalue % 10 + 0x30;
}else{
    USB_In_Buffer[2] = ADCONvalue % 10 + 0x30;
}
putUSBUSART(USB_In_Buffer, res);
```

Comment: Just so you know: HyperTerminal doesn't use ASCII; It uses the user-default code page (e.g., Windows-1252). Of course, any character set you are likely to use is a superset of ASCII with identical (8-bit) encodings for the shared characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to break down an `unsigned char` into decimal by dividing by 100, 10, and then using the remainder:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
   unsigned char val = 137;
   unsigned char res;

   printf("\n\nHundredths: %u\n", (int)((val / 100)));
   val = val % 100;
   printf("Tenths:     %u\n", (int)val / 10);
   printf("Ones:       %u\n", (int)val % 10);

   return 0;
}
```

The program outputs:

```
Hundredths: 1
Tenths:     3
Ones:       7
```

To convert to ASCII you ave to add 48 to each integer value. The ASCII codes for each of those numbers would be 49, 51, and 55.

Comment: Curious, why `"%u`" with `int` arguments?  Looks like dropping all the `(int)` cast would be better.

Answer (score 4):

Build an `IntToHex()` helper function.

```
static char IntToHex(unsigned x) {
  x &= 15;
  if (x <= 9) return x + '0';
  return x - 10 + 'A';
  }

unsigned char ADConverter;
char s[3];
s[0] = IntToHex(ADConverter >> 4);
s[1] = IntToHex(ADConverter);
s[2] = '\0';
send(s);
```

For the reverse see [hexadecimal ASCII chars conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17070973/how-to-reduce-the-code-space-for-a-hexadecimal-ascii-chars-conversion-using-a-s)

Answer (score 3):

You might like to look at the [`printf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) family of functions.

```
char str[32] = "";
unsigned char byte = 42;
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%hhu", byte); 
printf("'%s'", str); /* This is a debug statement to check what's be placed in str. */
```

prints out

```
'42'
```

---

Update referring the "send" function mentioned in the OP's update:

After having converted the integer vlaue of `byte` to its alphanumerical representation using `snprintf()` above, it could be place in the send buffer doing so:

```
putUSBUSART(str, strlen(str));
```

Comment: Please prefer `snprintf()` if available.

Comment: I would wonder if `printf` family is even available on his micro-controller.

Comment: But doesn't `printf` and `snprintf` write something on a terminal? I need to send it through USB to the pc, so I cant just print something.

Comment: @Bert `printf()` and family is typically available with PICs.  The extent of the parts, and its size, that may be incorporated sometimes depends on the fixed format parameter strings.  It is a bit expensive in code space for the whole package.

Comment: Apparantly using `sprintf()` , even though I'm including `<stdio.h>`, isn't supported in my compiler/device.

Answer (score 1):

A general purpose function for converting from a signed short binary value to a text string as decimal digits is provided below along with a companion function to convert an unsigned short binary value to a text string as hex digits.

I think if you change the `short` to `long` and the `unsigned short` to `unsigned long` the same logic would convert a signed long binary value to decimal digit text and an unsigned long binary value to hex digit text respectively.

```
/*
 *   char *ShortToString (short sVal, char *pOutText, int iLen)
 *
 *   Input:    sVal      - binary value as a signed short to convert to text
 *             pOutText  - pointer to a character array to receive the text
 *             iLen      - length of the character array in characters
 *
 *   Returns:  char * - saved value of pOutText, pointer to beginning of output buffer
 *
 *   Description:  Converts the signed binary value of sVal into a text string of decimal digits.
 *                 If the value of sVal is negative, a minus sign is the first character.
 *                 If the output buffer length is too small, astericks are put into the buffer.
 *
 *                 WARNING: Buffer must be sized to include a terminating zero for the end
 *                          of string character.
**/
char *ShortToString (short sVal, char *pOutText, int iLen)
{
    char *pOutTextSave = pOutText;
    char *pOutTextBegin = pOutText;

    if (sVal < 0) {
        sVal *= -1;
        *pOutText++ = '-';
    }
    pOutTextBegin = pOutText;    // remember where beginning of numeric string is

    // generate text digits in order from least significant to most significant
    do {
        *pOutText++ = (sVal % 10) + '0';  // convert least signicant decimal digit to text character
        sVal /= 10;                       // shift the binary value one decimal digit righ
    } while (sVal > 0 && pOutText + 1 < pOutTextSave + iLen);

    *pOutText = 0;   // end of string terminator
    pOutText--;      // back up one to point to last character.

    if (sVal) {
        // if there is insufficient room in the provided buffer for the string of digits
        // then indicate by filling the buffer with astericks.
        pOutTextBegin = pOutTextSave;
        while (pOutTextBegin + 1 < pOutTextSave + iLen) {*pOutTextBegin++ = '*'; }
        *pOutTextBegin = 0;   // end of string terminator
    } else {
        // reverse the string so that digits are in the right order,
        // most significant to least significant. we do this by swapping digits
        // until we come to the middle which means that everything is in order.
        while (pOutTextBegin < pOutText) {
            char k = *pOutTextBegin;
            *pOutTextBegin = *pOutText;
            *pOutText = k;
            pOutTextBegin++; pOutText--;
        }
    }

    return pOutTextSave;
}

/*
 *   char *HexShortToString (unsigned short usVal, char *pOutText, int iLen)
 *
 *   Input:    usVal     - binary value as an unsigned short to convert to text
 *             pOutText  - pointer to a character array to receive the text
 *             iLen      - length of the character array in characters
 *
 *   Returns:  char * - saved value of pOutText, pointer to beginning of output buffer
 *
 *   Description:  Converts the unsigned binary value of sVal into a text string of hex digits.
 *                 If the output buffer length is too small, astericks are put into the buffer.
 *
 *                 WARNING: Buffer must be sized to include a terminating zero for the end
 *                          of string character.
**/
char *HexShortToString (unsigned short usVal, char *pOutText, int iLen)
{
    char *pOutTextSave = pOutText;

    // generate text digits in order from least significant to most significant
    do {
        unsigned char uChar = usVal & 0x000f;

        *pOutText++ = (uChar < 10) ? uChar + '0' : uChar - 10 + 'A';  // convert least signicant hex digit to text character
        usVal >>= 4;                       // shift the binary value one hex digit righ
    } while (usVal > 0 && pOutText + 1 < pOutTextSave + iLen);

    *pOutText = 0;   // end of string terminator
    pOutText--;      // back up one to point to last character.

    if (usVal) {
        // if there is insufficient room in the provided buffer for the string of digits
        // then indicate by filling the buffer with astericks.
        pOutText = pOutTextSave;
        while (pOutText + 1 < pOutTextSave + iLen) {*pOutText++ = '*'; }
        *pOutText = 0;   // end of string terminator
    } else {
        char *pOutTextBegin = pOutTextSave;

        // reverse the string so that digits are in the right order,
        // most significant to least significant. we do this by swapping digits
        // until we come to the middle which means that everything is in order.
        while (pOutTextBegin < pOutText) {
            char k = *pOutTextBegin;
            *pOutTextBegin = *pOutText;
            *pOutText = k;
            pOutTextBegin++; pOutText--;
        }
    }

    return pOutTextSave;
}
```

A simple test harness is as follows.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char pOutBuff[16], pOutBuffHex[16];
    char *p, *pHex;
    short sVal, sLen;

    p = ShortToString((sVal = 0), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 0), pOutBuff, (sLen = 2));
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 1), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -1), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 2));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf ("     sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 2));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf ("     sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 3));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf ("     sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 3));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf ("     sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 4));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf ("     sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 4));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf ("     sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -12), pOutBuff, (sLen = 5));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf ("     sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 103), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -103), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 100), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -100), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 123), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -123), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 1234), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -1234), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 12345), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -12345), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = 32767), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);
    p = ShortToString((sVal = -32767), pOutBuff, (sLen = 15));
    pHex = HexShortToString(sVal, pOutBuffHex, sLen);
    printf (" sVal = %d  ShortToString() p = %s, 0x%x pHex=%s len = %d\n", sVal, p, sVal, pHex, sLen);

    return 0;
}
```

which produces the following output.

```
 sVal = 0  ShortToString() p = 0, 0x0 pHex=0 len = 15
 sVal = 0  ShortToString() p = 0 len = 2
 sVal = 1  ShortToString() p = 1, 0x1 pHex=1 len = 15
 sVal = -1  ShortToString() p = -1, 0xffffffff pHex=FFFF len = 15
 sVal = 12  ShortToString() p = 12, 0xc pHex=C len = 15
 sVal = -12  ShortToString() p = -12, 0xfffffff4 pHex=FFF4 len = 15
     sVal = 12  ShortToString() p = *, 0xc pHex=C len = 2
     sVal = -12  ShortToString() p = *, 0xfffffff4 pHex=* len = 2
     sVal = 12  ShortToString() p = 12, 0xc pHex=C len = 3
     sVal = -12  ShortToString() p = **, 0xfffffff4 pHex=** len = 3
     sVal = 12  ShortToString() p = 12, 0xc pHex=C len = 4
     sVal = -12  ShortToString() p = -12, 0xfffffff4 pHex=*** len = 4
     sVal = -12  ShortToString() p = -12, 0xfffffff4 pHex=FFF4 len = 5
 sVal = 103  ShortToString() p = 103, 0x67 pHex=67 len = 15
 sVal = -103  ShortToString() p = -103, 0xffffff99 pHex=FF99 len = 15
 sVal = 100  ShortToString() p = 100, 0x64 pHex=64 len = 15
 sVal = -100  ShortToString() p = -100, 0xffffff9c pHex=FF9C len = 15
 sVal = 123  ShortToString() p = 123, 0x7b pHex=7B len = 15
 sVal = -123  ShortToString() p = -123, 0xffffff85 pHex=FF85 len = 15
 sVal = 1234  ShortToString() p = 1234, 0x4d2 pHex=4D2 len = 15
 sVal = -1234  ShortToString() p = -1234, 0xfffffb2e pHex=FB2E len = 15
 sVal = 12345  ShortToString() p = 12345, 0x3039 pHex=3039 len = 15
 sVal = -12345  ShortToString() p = -12345, 0xffffcfc7 pHex=CFC7 len = 15
 sVal = 32767  ShortToString() p = 32767, 0x7fff pHex=7FFF len = 15
 sVal = -32767  ShortToString() p = -32767, 0xffff8001 pHex=8001 len = 15
```