# In Programming Code to Convert Lowercase to Uppercase why do we use(str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)?

Tags: c++, string, lowercase, toupper

**So this is the program I have used to Convert Lowercase, to Uppercase can you tell me why do we use this thing?[(str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)] in the following code section?**

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char str[20];
    int i;
    cout << "Enter the String (Enter First Name) : ";
    cin >> str;
    for (i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
        if (str[i] >= 97 && str[i] <= 122) //Why do we use this???
        {
            str[i] = str[i] - 32;
        }
    }
    cout << "\nThe String in Uppercase = " << str;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: An [ASCII table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ascii) might help you.

Comment: 97 is the ASCII code of `'a'`, 122 is the ASCII code of `'z'`. All the characters between (and including) them are usually known as "lowercase letters" aren't they?

Comment: And please, don't learn anything from this program as it is awful. It uses [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) which should be avoided. Doesn't use the perfectly fine [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) function. It relies on ASCII encoding and is therefore not portable. And it doesn't use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and is prone to buffer overflows.

Comment: Also, `#include<string.h>` is deprecated since the 90s and `#include<iostream.h>` as well as `void main` never was legal standard C++. You should get better and more up-tp-date code to learn from.

Comment: _if(str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)    //Why do we use this???_ Typically we use (if we **really** need it, which in modern C++ is rarely the case) `if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')`, since that is much more readable.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius if i use if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z') then an error is popping like~cannot convert "char" to char*

Comment: @Veritasian I fail to see how it is possible. Did you use double-quotes (`"`) instead of single-quotes (`'`) by any chance?

Comment: @Veritasian Yet you post the correct code in the comment. Interesting.

Comment: ** if(str[i]>="a" && str[i]<="z")
     {
  str[i]=str[i]-32;
     } @AlgirdasPreidžius this is what i did

Comment: This is wrong because you used `"` instead of `'` `"` is used for strings. `'` is used for a character.

Comment: @Veritasian Then you **didn't** use my example. Have a look at it again.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i got the code now!!! Thanks to all :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius: `if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')` is still not portable. This trick does work for `'0'` to `'9'` because C++ makes a special guarantee for digits to have consecutive numeric representations, but not for letters.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Yes, I know that. My point was, that it is a lot more readable (and intention is a lot more clear) than OPs original version, using magic numbers.

Comment: Even if written in "portable" code, this algorithm is inadequate to convert characters to uppercase. Casing rules depend on the writing system and language (see setlocale()). (Even if your problem domain has only English text, there are more letter characters used than a-z and A-Z.) That's why there are libraries.

Answer (score 7):

This part of the code is very badly written:

```
if(str[i]>=97 && str[i]<=122)
{
 str[i]=str[i]-32;
}
```

It would be much more portable and more readable as:

```
if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')
{
 str[i]=str[i]-'a'+'A';
}
```

or better still, use standard C library macros/functions (from `<ctype.h>`):

```
if(islower(str[i]))
{
 str[i]=toupper((unsigned char)str[i]);
}
```

or even better yet, you can just skip the test completely and write:

```
str[i]=toupper((unsigned char)str[i]);
```

(since `toupper` will return the char unchanged if it's not a lower case letter).

Comment: Even better would be to simply say `str[i] = toupper((unsigned char)str[i])`.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: yes, thanks, still working on refining the answer... ;-)

Comment: "more readable" of course. "much more portable" yes, but still not completely, because there is no guarantee that `'a'` to `'z'` have consecutive numerical representations.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: true, the original implementation and my first version fail for EBCDIC, hence the further improvements using `<ctype.h>` that I gave further down in the answer.

Comment: `toupper()` without a cast to `unsigned char` may lead to undefined behavior if a "negative" char is encountered.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: good point - got to make sure we handle "extended ASCII" et al properly.

Answer (score 3):

97 is the decimal representation of the ascii character `a`, while 122 is `z`.

So if your character (which is simply a byte) is inside this interval, it is a lowercase letter. Substracting 32 will make it uppercase.

Note that in this case, writing `str[i] <= 122` or `str[i] <= 'z'` are equivalent.

[image: ascii table]

Comment: @axiac: When was the last time you checked? They might have changed it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley 5 minutes ago :-)

Comment: *"Note that in C, str[i] <= 122 and str[i] <= 'z' are equivalent."* - No, they are not. `'z'` may or may not be 122. In practice, you may never encounter a system on which it's not 122, but there is no guarantee. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29381142/3313064

Answer (score 2):

This would be more appropriate code:

```
if(str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')
 {
 str[i]=str[i] + 'A' - 'a';
 }
}
```

No numbers, and if a letter is between lowercase 'a' and lowercase 'z', it gets transposed by the difference between 'A' and 'a', and as such becoming its uppercase version.

Answer (score 2):

That is specific to ASCII, where the lowercase letters have the numeric values  97-122.  This has the useful property that the uppercase characters (which are mapped from 65-90) can be converted to lower case with a constant subtraction or  a bitwise operation (and vice versa).

However, it's bad in general to assume that every system out there uses ASCII; there are other character sets out there.  You should be using the library functions `toupper` and `tolower` from the header `<cctype>`.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the range of lower-case characters in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/).