# C++ array declaration and initialization

Tags: c++, vector

While watching a tutorial the speaker used

`int deca['f' + '9' + 2 ] = {0};`

I've never seen this on any other `C++` tutorial and they didn't explain what it meant, and when I tried to implement it on my computer an error showed up.

As reference they were in a Linux environment.

Comment: What is the error that showed up?

Comment: can you share the reference of the tutorial ?

Comment: What error did you get?  [Works just fine here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e0ce8ccd400fc76)

Comment: The title of your question may be misleading, as the line of code you provide declares an array, and not a vector.

Comment: `'f'` is another reprensetation of 102, and `'9'` of 57. so. `'f' + '9' + 2 ` is equal to 161. `int deca['f' + '9' + 2 ]` instanciate an array with 161 elements. It's not a vector

Comment: `{0}` is a list initialization in `c++` please refer to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: _While watching a tutorial the speaker used..._ : and what did the speaker say?

Comment: @Garf365: values of `'f'` and `'9'` are implementation specific. you just provide ascii values which are the most popular. See [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for counter example.

Comment: @MichaelWalz he didn't say anything, he just declared it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It simply declares an integer array of `N` elements and initializes it to zero. What `N` evaluates to is determined by the `'f' + '9' + 2` expression. It evaluates to `161` if you are using ASCII code page or something else if you are using different code page. Every character literal has its corresponding integral value depending on the encoding used. In ASCII code page the character `'f'` is represented by a number of `102` and the character `'9'` has a value of `57`. The expression becomes `102 + 57 + 2` which equals `161`. In other code pages those characters might have other values. Equivalent of:

```
int deca[161] = { 0 };  // If ASCII code page is used
```

Comment: That's only true if your system uses ASCII, which is not guaranteed [see related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381067/does-c-and-c-guarantee-the-ascii-of-a-f-and-a-f-characters)

Comment: @Borgleader Indeed. Updated the answer.

Comment: I think you mean _encoding_, not _code page_.  Those two terms mean different things.  E.g., a machine need not support _code pages_ to have an _encoding_.

Comment: @HWalters I think you are right. I have updated the answer.