# What's the best way to guarantee ASCII both at compile-time and run-time?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

I am inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381067/does-c-and-c-guarantee-the-ascii-of-a-f-and-a-f-characters#answer-29381136).

The one way I thought of was a combination of `static_assert` (C11-onwards) and `assert`.

Basically, an `ascii.h` file with a bunch of

```
static_assert(' ' == 32);
static_assert('!' == 33);
// ...
```

statements and then a function

```
static void assert_runtime_ascii(void) {
    assert(' ' == 32);
    assert('!' == 33);
    // ...
}
```

to be executed in `main`.

This is way too verbose (200+ lines) making this impractical, so I just comment this

```
// NOTE: this program expects ASCII both at run-time and compile-time.
```

and be done.

Is there a better way?

I could not find a `#define` like `__STDC_IEC_559__` for ASCII in the standard.

Is there a better way?

Comment: In what way is it impractical? Just include the file.

Comment: Practically speaking, you don't need 200 lines. If `' ' == 32`, `'!' == 33`, `'0' == 48`, `'A' == 65`, and `'a' == 97'`, you can be 99+% sure you have an ASCII-compatible character set (possibly Latin-1 or some flavor of Unicode). Check a few more punctuation characters if you're concerned about old 7-bit character sets that shove regional characters into the ASCII range. But keep in mind that if your code is compiled on a non-ASCII system, it will have been translated from the ASCII encoding in which you typed it.

Comment: Possibly use a hash-value of a few `const char` strings?

Comment: What's the point in asserting ASCII encoding? When you build your code, you **know** the encoding of the OS on that particular architecture, so you don't have to check anything, when you can pass a `-DNOT_ASCII=1` option to the compiler.

Comment: "too verbose (200+ lines)" is unclear as ASCII only defines 128 characters.

Comment: `assert(' ' == 32);` is not really run-time check as the code may be optimized  at compile time.

Comment: You could make the code more compact with something like assert(0 == strcmp(
" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~",
"\040\041\042\043\044\045\046\047\050\051\052\053\054\055\056\057\060\061\062\063\064\065\066\067\070\071\072\073\074\075\076\077\100\101\102\103\104\105\106\107\110\111\112\113\114\115\116\117\120\121\122\123\124\125\126\127\130\131\132\133\134\135\136\137\140\141\142\143\144\145\146\147\150\151\152\153\154\155\156\157\160\161\162\163\164\165\166\167\170\171\172\173\174\175\176"
));

Comment: @Pablo "When you build your code, you know the encoding of the OS on that particular architecture" --> Not always as code is ported and shared.  A fair amount of code compiling involves automation - there is no programmer to "know"

Comment: @Gene Needs a little work with `...[\]...` --> `...[\\]...` and perhaps also test `\t\v\n\f`.  Looks like a foundation for more than just a comment.

Answer (score 0):

> best way to guarantee ASCII both at compile-time and run-time?

It sounds like OP wants to know how to detect the *execution character set* encoding and user I/O encoding.

At compile time **or** run-time, to detect ASCII, use a series of `_Static_asserts` or `asserts` [(example code)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/216017/29485) for most of the 128 [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters, the ones that are part of the C language *execution character set*.  C11 §5.2.1 3

```
A to Z
a to z
0 to 9
! " # % & ’ ( ) * + , - . / : ; < = > ? [ \ ] ^ _ { | } ~
space character, 
  and control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, and form feed.
some way of indicating the end of each line of text
```

Note that characters like "$, @,`" are not part of the *execution character set* so "if there is no corresponding member, it is converted to an implementation-defined member other than the null (wide) character" applies.

---

To detect encoding of user input/output, I do not see a solution short of asking the user to enter a reference text and code checking it.