# In a C programming I'm checking if the input character is Lowercase or Upper! But I want that user only input single character else display invalid

Tags: c

I tried it using logical operations and if else statement.

I tried to fix it with conditional statements but didn't work.

```
// Here is the code.

#include <stdio.h>

void checkCase(char character) {
    if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {
        printf("The input character is a lowercase letter.\n");
    } else if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z') {
        printf("The input character is an uppercase letter.\n");
    } else {
        printf("The input is not a letter or is neither lowercase nor uppercase.\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    char userInput;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &userInput);
    
    checkCase(userInput);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Define "didn't work" -- what output did you expect, and what output did you actually get?  Note that the C standard library provides the `isupper` and `islower` functions (declared in `ctype.h`) to do exactly this.

Comment: [How to avoid pressing Enter with getchar() for reading a single character only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798511/how-to-avoid-pressing-enter-with-getchar-for-reading-a-single-character-only)

Comment: Tangential fun fact: there's strictly speaking no guarantee that that letters `a-z` or `A-Z` are contiguous in C. See [Does C and C++ guarantee the ASCII of \[a-f\] and \[A-F\] characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29381067/11082165)

Comment: @Brian61354270: I don't think "fun" means what you think it means :)

Comment: @ScottHunter: Yes, it does.

Comment: you can read the next character and verify that it is indeed a '\n' for the input to be valid.

Comment: Edit the question to explain exactly what you want the program to do and what you observed it do instead. It is not clear whether you want the program to expect a single character per line and to ignore the new-line character that marks the end of a line or whether you want the program to receive a character as soon as the user presses a key, even if they do not press Enter or Return.

Comment: Avoid putting too much detail in the title. The part "_But I want that user only input single character else display invalid_" is not dealt with in your code. With `%c` you will not be able to tell how many characters were entered.  At least two, the character in `userInput` and _newline_.  It is not clear from your question body if that is the part that "does not work" and it is not clear what you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Standard input is line buffered by default at multiple levels:

- the standard input `stream` uses its own buffering system, which you can disable with `setvbuf`
- the terminal to which it is tied has its own line policy, which is also line buffered by default. Disabling this required system dependent APIs, such as `tcsetattr` on unix systems.

You need to set both layers as unbuffered for the program to receive characters as soon as they are typed by the user.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <termios.h>

void checkCase(char character) {
    if (character >= 'a' && character <= 'z') {
        printf("\nThe input character is a lowercase letter.\n");
    } else if (character >= 'A' && character <= 'Z') {
        printf("\nThe input character is an uppercase letter.\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nThe input is not a letter or is neither lowercase nor uppercase.\n");
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char userInput;
    struct termios tty, oldtty;

    tcgetattr(0, &tty);
    oldtty = tty;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tty);

    setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &userInput);

    checkCase(userInput);

    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &oldtty);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Ankit: you can accept an answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I didn't get your idea but here is simple solution.

Without digging into terminal *termios* settings and line discipline, you can slightly modify your main() function to take string
instead on char, and then use format string to check how many characters were entered, like here:

```
int main() {
    char userInput[20];
    int len;
    printf("Enter a character: ");
    scanf("%20s%n", userInput, &len);
    if (len > 1)
        printf("ERROR, more than one character:%d\n", len);
    
    checkCase(userInput[0]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what happens if the user enters `alsdqoiewlfmasdjvoqmweqmmpoqwjefmqhjf`?

Comment: probably overruns and corrupts the stack frame since userInput is local variable allocated on stack, I forgot to add a width in string format specifier to limit number of characters scanf will put in it.