# Shortest way to convert hex char to int in C?

Tags: c, char, hex

I'm looking for the least amount of code in C, in order to convert a char to int, where it flags -1 (or any error flag) if the char is not a valid hex digit.

here's what I came up with, is there a shorter way?

```
// input example
char input = 'f';   

// conversion segment
int x = input - '0';    
if (!((x >= 49 && x <= 54) || (x >= 0 &&  x <= 9))) x = -1;
if (x > 9) x -= 39;

// test print   
printf("%d", x);
```

Comment: And posters act like they forgot about `'A'`

Comment: What do you want the character `'a'` to be converted to?

Comment: @kaylum `10` presumably

Comment: I'd like 'a' to be converted to 10, 'f' to be 15, '0' to '9' to be their integer equivalents, and any other char not in those ranges to return -1. Trying to see the least amount of lines this can be done in.

Comment: There isn't a standard function that does that directly.  You could use `if (sscanf(&c, "%1x", &x) != 1) x = -1;` at a pinch.  Alternatively, you can play is `isdigit()` and `isxdigit()` (and maybe `isupper()` or `islower()`) from `<ctype.h>` to work out what to do.  Or create a lookup table for possible (unsigned) `char` values initialized with `-1` except for the valid hex digits.

Comment: I only ask because in the proposed option `'a' - '0'` gives `49`. So it's definetely not the shortest way as it is not a solution.

Comment: don't use hardcode values like 48, 57, 97 or 102. Use 'a', 'z', 'A', 'Z'... instead

Comment: sorry kaylum, I corrected the ascii values. Why did someone vote to close? I don't see another question that addresses this and I'm sure someone looking to shorten up their code may find it useful.

Comment: "shorten up the code" is something you do for Obfuscated C contests. Any actual programmer would just write normal code using obvious logic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because writing shortest code may be fun, but is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
isxdigit(c);
```

Comment: I knew there was a way! By the way for anyone else it requires `<ctype.h>`

Comment: Actually this would have be more nice if it returned the int equivalent value rather than a 1, but still shortens things up a bit.

Comment: This does not convert per the post's title "convert hex char to int", it simply tests (true/false) if a character is a hexadecimal character - and takes a 256 bit/byte table to do it.

Comment: I agree. It only tests. But, as i understood it, the questions was also about getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

This code assumes ASCII and converts all 256 characters codes into 256 different codes, partially `'0'-'9' 'A'-'F'` map to `0,1,...15`.

For additional tricks and simplification see the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17070973/2410359)

```
unsigned char ch = GetData(); // Fetch 1 byte of incoming data;
if (!(--ch & 64)) {           // decrement, then if in the '0' to '9' area ...
  ch = (ch + 7) & (~64);      // move 0-9 next to A-Z codes
}
ch -= 54;                     // -= 'A' - 10 - 1
if (ch > 15) { 
  ; // handle error
}
```