# How to write() hexadecimal representation of \n?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to `write()` hexadecimal representation of `\n` without any success.

The code I have `ft_putstr_non_printable.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putstr_non_printable(char *str)
{
    int             i;
    unsigned char   a;
    char            c;

    i = 0;
    a = 0x0;
    while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (str[i] <= 31 || str[i] == 127)
        {
            a = str[i];
            write(1, &a, 1);
        }
        else
        {
            c = str[i];
            write(1, &c, 1);
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

And `main.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "ft_putstr_non_printable.c"

int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "\n au revoir\a";
    char b[] = "omellette du fromage\b";
    char c[] = "coeuf@ca6va\e fef";
    char d[] = " Batata \x7F rfg";
    char e[] = "roquefort`[e{forte-e_tem,bolor \n feff";
    char f[] = " we 9are 78familly \x1F rgfenf";

    ft_putstr_non_printable(a);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(b);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(c);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(d);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(e);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(f);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? How do I get \x0a?

Edit: I can't use `printf()`. I'm limited to `write()`.

Comment: Well, `write(1, &a, 1);` and `write(1, &c, 1);` are basically identical, so you're not going to accomplish it that way.  `write` is not like `printf`.  `write` is a low-level function that just writes raw bytes.  To get `\n` to come out as `0a` or `0x0a` means you're going to have to write two or more bytes, and this in turn means you're going to have to construct those two or more bytes somehow.  The simplest way is `sprintf`, if that's allowed.

Comment: To print the hexadecimal representation of `\n` (well any character) do: `printf("%02x", '\n');`

Comment: Study the string library.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid `printf` for whatever reason, you're looking for a function such as `itoa` that converts a number to a string. Then you'll have to explicitly print each character

Comment: @JakobLovern cant use itoa either only func I can use is write

Comment: Given that itoa isn't a POSIX standard, no wonder you can't use it. You can, however, write your own implementation inside `ft_putstr_non_printable`

Comment: Suggestion: Never `#include` `.c` files, like you do in `#include "ft_putstr_non_printable.c"`

Comment: Also, `\e` is a non-standard escape sequence. What do you want with that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead writing one character when `str[i]` is out of the printable range, form a little string and write that.

```
    // if (str[i] <= 31 || str[i] == 127)
    if (str[i] <= 31 || str[i] >= 127) {
        unsigned char a = str[i];
        char buf[5];
        int len = sprintf(buf, "\\x%02X", a);
        // write(1, &a, 1);
        write(1, buf, len);
    }
```

---

> I'm limited to write()

If `sprintf()` not available:

```
        // int len = sprintf(buf, "\\x%02X", a);
        buf[0] = '\\'; 
        buf[1] = 'x'; 
        buf[2] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[a/16];
        buf[3] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[a%16];
        buf[4] = '\0';
        len = 4;
```

---

Advanced:

`char` may be *unsigned*, so values above 127 are possible.

To well reverse the process it might make sense to print the `\\` in hex.

```
    if (str[i] <= 31 || str[i] >= 127 || str[i] == '\\') {
```

Comment: `buf[2] = "0123456789ABCDEF"[a%16];` Love it... I had completely forgotten that little trick. Nice.

Comment: @4386427 If code needs to be real small, could user [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17070973/2410359).

Comment: @chux what do you mean with the advanced part and can you clarify what is happening in `0123456789ABCDEF"[a/16];` here?

Comment: @MiguelM `"0123456789ABCDEF"` is a _string_.  `a/16` divides the `a` by 16 with a quotient of 0 to 15.   Then `[quotient]` indexes the string resulting in the `quotient`'th `char`.

Comment: "0123456789ABCDEF"[a%16] the only problem is that the compiler may or not use the same literal :)-

Comment: @0___________ True about compiler may/may not use same string in the 2 lines of code (thus a coding efficiency concern). Functions correctly either way.

Comment: @0___________ How so?

Comment: @MiguelM It does not matter for you. Not related to your problem

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica can you explain the last str[i] == '\\' please?

Comment: @MiguelM he has explained

Comment: @MiguelM `last str[i] == '\\'` tests if the character is a backslash.  Say the output was "\x0a".  Was that due to input line-feed or "\\x0a"?   By printing the single character `'\\'` as "\x5C" we have distinctive output.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica sorry I am still not understanding

Comment: @MiguelM If input string was a single line feed character, `'\n'`, what output is desired? If input was the 4 character string: backslash, 'x', '0', 'a', what output is desired?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Ohhhhhh

Answer (score 1):

*Notice:*

*I recommend the answer from chux - Reinstate Monica due to the nice conversion from 0..15 to hex.*

*See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68307913/4386427*

*I'll leave this answer as-is just in case someone should prefer this code-wise longer way of doing the conversion*

**Answer**

Given all your restriction (which prevents normal code), you may be looking for:

```
char a = '\n';  // Or any other char
char h;
unsigned char tmp;

tmp = a;
tmp = tmp / 16;
if (tmp < 10)
{
    h = '0' + tmp;
}
else
{
    h = 'a' + tmp - 10;
}
write(1,&h,1);

tmp = a
tmp = tmp % 16;
if (tmp < 10)
{
    h = '0' + tmp;
}
else
{
    h = 'a' + tmp - 10;
}
write(1,&h,1);
```

**Output**

```
0a
```

Answer (score 1):

I have wrapped the hex output into `[]` to make them mo distinct.

```
#include <unistd.h>

void    ft_putstr_non_printable(const char *s)
{
    const char *hex = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    const unsigned char *str = s;
    while (*str)
    {
        if (*str <= 31 || *str >= 127)
        {
            char hexrep[] = {'[','0','x', hex[*str >> 4], hex[*str & 0x0f],']'};
            write(1, hexrep, sizeof(hexrep));
        }
        else
        {
            write(1, str, 1);
        }
        str++;
    }
    write(1, (char[]){'\n'},1);
}


int main(void)
{
    char a[] = "\n au revoir\a";
    char b[] = "omellette du fromage\b";
    char c[] = "coeuf@ca6va\e fef";
    char d[] = " Batata \x7F rfg";
    char e[] = "roquefort`[e{forte-e_tem,bolor \n feff";
    char f[] = " we 9are 78familly \x1F rgfenf";

    ft_putstr_non_printable(a);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(b);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(c);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(d);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(e);
    ft_putstr_non_printable(f);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zq7sPfM6q

Output:

```
[0x0A] au revoir[0x07]
omellette du fromage[0x08]
coeuf@ca6va[0x1B] fef
 Batata [0x7F] rfg
roquefort`[e{forte-e_tem,bolor [0x0A] feff
 we 9are 78familly [0x1F] rgfenf
```

If you want to have `\xHH` format suimply change one line to:

```
            char hexrep[] = {'\\','x', hex[*str >> 4], hex[*str & 0x0f]};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6GonenfK7

Output:

```
\x0A au revoir\x07
omellette du fromage\x08
coeuf@ca6va\x1B fef
 Batata \x7F rfg
roquefort`[e{forte-e_tem,bolor \x0A feff
 we 9are 78familly \x1F rgfenf
```

Comment: `hex[*str >> 4]`, likely a problem when `*str < 0`. Perhaps force to an `unsigned char`?

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option:

```
void ft_putstr_non_printable(const char *str) {
    static const char hex[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    int outfd = fileno(stdout);
    char buf[4] = {'0', 'x'};
    unsigned char ch; // used to convert the usually signed `char` to unsigned

    for(; (ch = *str) != '\0'; ++str) {    // loop until null terminator
        if (ch < ' ' || ch > '~') {        // outside printable ASCII range?
            // pick the last two chars in `buf` from the hex array:
            buf[2] = hex[ch >> 4];         // the high nibble
            buf[3] = hex[ch & 0xF];        // the low nibble
            write(outfd, buf, sizeof buf); // ex: writes 0x7F if ch == 127
        } else {
            write(outfd, &ch, 1);
        }
    }
    ch = '\n';
    write(outfd, &ch, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `write()` actually do? It's defined in `<unistd.h>` as:

> ```c
> ssize_t write(int fildes, const void *buf, size_t nbyte);
> ```

It **write**s to a **filedes**criptor. It writes from a **buf**fer and writes `nbytes` bytes from that memory location.

Thus when you pass `&i` to it, write just sees memory addresses. It doesn't see an `int`. Likewise with `&c`. What you need to do is turn each character (as a number) into a string representing the character. The code for `ft_putstr_non_printable` would look something like:

```c
void ft_putstr_non_printable(char *str)
{
    int             i;
    unsigned char   a;
    i = 0;
    const char[] hexchars = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    for (int ii = 0;str[i]!='\0';ii++)
    {
        a = str[i];
        if (str[i]> 31 && str[i] < 127)
            write(1, &a, 1);
        else
        {
            write(1,'[',1);
            if (a<=16
            while (a!=0)
            {
                write(1,hexchars+(a%16),1);
                a/=16;
            }
            write(1,']',1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is basically how `itoa()` works. @4386427's answer is more elegant for single byte characters, but I wanted to explicitly show how one would do it in a `while` loop.

Comment: Code is printing the hex value in little endian order.  Was that intended?  Note: `while (a!=0) { write(1,hexchars+(a%16),1); a/=16; }` write 1 or 2 characters - that leads to ambiguity if a 1 character hex output is followed by a digit character.

Comment: Unfortunately, for n-ary escape codes that ambiguity is inevitable. (It's basically the String problem all over again: Either prepend with the number of characters or append with a code ender.) I've chosen to adopt bracketed notation. It's not as good but it gets the job done.

Comment: As for endianness, I don't know how to fix that without either an endian reverse operation or complicated modulo math... Or pushing to a stack similar to what you did.